# error in strings.xml in doing widget @<drawable />

Tags: android, xml, android-widget

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Widget_demo</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <drawable />
</resources>
```

Here I am getting the following error in line `<drawable />`:

```
error: A 'name' attribute is required for `<drawable>`
```

Comment: The editor should give you the line the error is on which should give you a clue

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<string name="app_name">Widget_demo</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<drawable /> // remove this
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Widget_demo</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

Also go through the docs

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

remove following:

```
<drawable />
```